# Predict two value [SUP, INF] instead of one value

Tags: r, svm, prediction

I need to predict 2 values from a database. 
For now, I just predict one value with svm regression and I add a coeff to every prediction like that :

```
mypred_SUP <- mypred + 0.5
mypred_INF <- mypred - 0.5
```

Is there a better way to predict two values ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to predict 2 values from your training data: the mean which is `mypred` for you, and the standard deviation of your prediction.

You should look at the Gaussian Processes, that constructs a predictor with a combination of Gaussian variables. An advantage of such model is that they also predict an estimation of the prediction error, often referred as confidence interval.

There are many available tools that can do that, opensource and commercial. You can maybe start with GPy: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/index.ipynb
More tools are listed here: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multi Target Regression, The MULAN tool has state-of-the-art algorithms to solve those kinds of problem [MULAN](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/datasets-mtr.html). 
Multi target regression is the term used when there are multiple dependent variables.